# family sharing - no apps are showing on other family member devices

Tags: ios-appstore, family-sharing

So I setup family sharing with myself as the organizer. I invited several family members and they're using their own Apple ID on the iTunes section of the iDevice's settings.

When my wife went to Appstore => Updates => Purchased Apps => my name, no apps are showing. I'm pretty sure I haven't hidden anything and even if I did, I'm pretty sure I didn't hide ALL the apps I've bought under my name.

In saying that, I setup Family-sharing on my Macbook since it's easier to type but I don't think that matters?

Any ideas on how to fix it? thanks

edit: just logged in again to iCloud using my Apple ID and I have enabled "Share my purchases".

Answer (score 1):

I've had the purchases tab take 30 seconds to 30 minutes to render in the past. The stores are extremely busy and I'm seeing higher error rates than normal for updates, downloads and such.

I would say, give it 24 hours after you set up the family sharing for things to get sorted out before contacting Apple.

You should also get an email notification from Apple when each person you invited accepts the sharing of apps portion of the plan. They have to opt in to share so everyone should get emails when people join and leave the party, so to speak.

If you want to reach out to Apple - use the iTunes Store Support team as they handle accounts, purchases, billing and such.

- https://www.apple.com/support/itunes/

Comment: I've setup family sharing like 2 days ago though... and I didn't send them invitation. since they're around, I just let them type their password on my MacBook so I can add them.

Comment: Hmm - Maybe unenroll one and send the invite? Since it's two days, a request to support might already be in order though.